Timer in Lightning Web Component (LWC) not synced across multiple instances on different systems
We are implemented the LWC for timer.
So in that we have buttons of start and stop for handle the timer.
now if we started the timer on my system and if anyone open the same page of running timer on another system then on that system the timer is visible as null.
and here we are using the same login in both systems.

All software runs on one device at a time. For example, even if you log in to my org using my credentials, you can't see what I have stored in, for example, localStorage. In order to coordinate data, each copy of software needs a way to communicate to other copies of the software. In Salesforce, this is usually done by storing a record in the database.
For your specific component, it should check if there is any stored data about the state of the timer (e.g. previously elapsed time and current lap start time), and then start from that position, and when a lap is started, that data should be stored to the server so it can be loaded when the page loads again, and when stopped, should store the total elapsed time and clear the running flags.
The component's controller might look like this:
export default class Timer extends LightningElement {
  elapsedTime;
  currentStartTime;
  intervalId;
  async connectedCallback() {
    const timerData = await getTimerData();
    Object.assign(this, timerData);
    if(this.currentStartTime) {
      this.startTimer();
    }
  }
  startTimer() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.timerTick, 1000);
  }
  async stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    saveTimerData({ 
      elapsedTime: this.elapsedTime, 
      currentStartTime: null, 
    });
  }
  timerTick = () => {
    // Timer implementation
  }
  handleStartClick() {
    this.startTimer();
  }
  handleStopClick() {
    this.stopTimer();
  }
}

You may need more sophisticated means of time tracking, such as synchronizing start and stop events across devices so you don't "double-count" the time, for example, or perhaps storing each time session individually, or tracking multiple timers
There's no "one right way" to solve this problem, just know that it requires storing data in a way that's accessible to all instances of the component.

Relates to this Q&A.
